# Java default version doesnt reflect after PATH change

Tags: java, version, environment-variables

I am running currently on Java 1.7.0_17  64bit version and I want to launch an app using Java 32 bit version.

I updated PATH variable to point to `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin)` Java 32 bit version. Then did a `java -version` it still shows the 64bit version.

I gave up and tried to do a `java -d32 -jar abc.jar` and then it gives me an

```
java -d32
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

Please let me know how can the system refresh the latest Java settings done in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is probably a `java.exe` in your `C:\WINDOWS\System32\` folder leftover from the previous installation. Replace it with the one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`.

Comment: thanks. there are other related java exe's as well in the System32 folder. javaw.exe and javaws.exe should i replace them as well with Java 32 bit version. I am not sure if there are other related java files in the system 32 which I dont replace and the whole thing will be a mess. Or just replacing java.exe shuld do?

Comment: @Java You should replace all of them if you want the 32 bit `java` to be the default. Otherwise, you can execute `java` from its full path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java -version`.

Comment: cygwin was driving my crazy with its own path's and escape characters. But it worked now. I still wonder when I change the PATH variable doesnt windows update it in system32. I wonder whats the point of updating the PATH if its not reflected accordingly. Does it need a system reboot or something?

Comment: @Java What you changed was the `PATH` environment variable to use your new Java installation's path. But Windows prioritizes the paths in `PATH`, first looking in `system32` before anything else. If you used the windows installer to install Java, it most likely copied the `java*.exe` files to `system32`. The `PATH` environment variable is just a String, it doesn't execute anything.