# how to revert back to java 6?

Tags: java, java-6

I upgraded to java and set to following advance envirnment variables frrom windows UI(not by command prompt)

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
PATH = %JAVA_HOME\bin%
```

when i do `java  - version` it reflects the right java version as "1.7.0_51"

but when i try to revert back to jav java 6 after reverting java_home (from windows UI )back to

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43
PATH = %JAVA_HOME\bin%
```

i opened new commad prompt but `java  - version` still reflects the java version as `"1.7.0_51"`

**should it not reflect java version as.6.0_43 ? Can't i go back to java 6 just by reverting java_home?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410555/java-default-version-doesnt-reflect-after-path-change?rq=1 tried this?

Comment: It's not clear where you're running any of this... are you editing the environment variables in a command prompt - and then starting another command prompt? Note that JAVA_HOME is basically irrelevant in most cases.

Comment: @Jon Skeet updated my post to make it more clear

Comment: Right, if you did that in the Windows UI then it would only change the user-specified part of the path - so C:\WINDOWS\System32\ would still be earlier in your path. Type `PATH` in your command prompt to see the full path and check.

Comment: When i type PATH i see "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin". so why java -version still reflect java 7?

Comment: @user3198603: Is that *all* you see? I see half a page of stuff...

Comment: here is complete value "PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualiza
tion Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Progra
m Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
 Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C

Comment: :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C
:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files\C
ode Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files\Quest Software\JProbe 9.0.1\bin;C:\apac
he-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6
.0_43\bin;C:\Program Files\Quest Software\JProbe 9.0.1\bin"

Comment: Also i am using 64 bit java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45569/discussion-between-user3198603-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Jon Skeet is java version  is reading from some registry file instead of java_home?

Comment: `java -version` finds the first `java.exe` on the system path and executes it. That `java.exe` has a version associated with it. If this `java.exe` is in `System32`, then it is actually a stub which will read the registry to find out which `java.exe` to delegate to, based on the current Java version setting in the registry.

Comment: Solution: either place a Java `bin` directory on the *system-wide* PATH, as the first entry in it, or edit the registry to change the default java version.

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik . Thanks . One more question. I can revert back to java 6 just by changing the path and classpath. Right? i dont have to change anywhere else . Right? Can we quick chat for 5 minutes. i am bit stuck after java 7 upgrade. I would be greatful if can give me 5 minuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a java.exe in your C:\WINDOWS\System32\ folder leftover from the previous installation. Replace it with the one in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin.